# Do old dogs run away to die?

Tags: mortality, dogs

My dog passed away a few days ago. He ran away from home early in the morning, and by the time we found him it was late afternoon and he was very weak, on the brink of death. Soon after we brought him home, he drifted off and stopped breathing.

I was feeling very horrible thinking about what might have happened to him in the hours before we found him, and that he might still be alive if we had somehow stopped him from running away. But a few people comforted me, saying that a lot of old dogs run away from home when its time to die. Perhaps they like to die alone?

I'm wondering if there's any truth to this?

Notability: http://www.ehow.com/info_12047757_dogs-run-away-dying.html

Comment: not proof, but my cat also ran away to die, and i was also told that this was common that animals like a secluded place to die. so a +1 on this being a claim

Comment: The same is said for [elephants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephants'_graveyard)

Comment: [Cross-posted on Pets.](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10364/do-old-dogs-run-away-to-die) Please don't do this.

Comment: @nomenagentis: What kind of evidence would convince you?

Comment: @ HDE 226868 Are we not supposed to cross-post? Apologies, I didn't know.

Comment: Run away from what? Run away to be alone? Or are they alone and then run away to not be alone?

Comment: I heard a variation on this from a vet in which animals that are below par (from wounds or sickness) hide to escape unwelcome attention while they wait to heal/strength. In that scenario the running away isn't "to die" as such, it's just that this time they didn't make it.

Comment: Running away to die is not one of the recognized symptoms of canine cognitive dysfunction affecting geriatric dogs researched here-http://www.ava.com.au/sites/default/files/AVA_website/pdfs/NSW_Division/VETS%20%2B%20NURSES%20COMBINED%20-%20Kersti%20Seksel%20-%20Canine%20Cognitive%20Dysfunction.pdf, here-http://animalnecessity.com/doc/research/Serenin/Behavior-Problems-in-a-Dog.pdf and here-http://www.banfield.com/getmedia/7a12c617-3ec6-4a67-9fdb-ede9273f5f9c/673ef271-4b8a-44e3-94e3-5c2ebb2ed01b-pdf0

Answer (score 2):

According to [The Complete Tracker, 2nd edition: Tracks, Signs, and Habits of North American Wildlife](https://books.google.com/books?id=2aMBOE02xh4C&pg=PA117&dq=sick%20wolves%20leave%20the%20pack&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimm9rfi_jMAhXEQyYKHW_tABsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=sick%20wolves%20leave%20the%20pack&f=false), Chapter 12, DOGS (CANIDAE), page 117

> Pack members are brought food if they become sick or injured, but these wolves often leave the pack voluntarily

See also [On the effects of domestication on canine social development and behavior](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304376282902152)

> deposed alpha animals are either ejected from the pack, leave the pack voluntarily